# stored PL/sql function using select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Example i have a stored pl/sql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE number( test in NUMBER )
........
// rest of code
```

isn't possible that i don't want run this execute

```
execute number(2);
```

i want run with

```
select * from number(2);
```

isn't possible to run stored pl/sql script with select statement to call the function instead of execute?

Comment: If you want to get output back from number, then 1) number has to be defined as a function, and 2) instead of using a select statement, you should simply use an assignment, as `x := number(2);`.

Comment: @josephB
this is just an example that pass with parameter . 
but i want to use stored pl/sql as my question wanted. and then use select to output it

Comment: You cannot select from a stored procedure using the SELECT statement. Please refer http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't execute a PROCEDURE from SQL; however, you *can* execute a FUNCTION from SQL.

First, redefine NUMBER as a FUNCTION:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NUMBER(pTest IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
  someValue NUMBER := pTest * 100;
BEGIN
  -- whatever
  RETURN someValue;
END;
```

Then execute it from a SELECT statement as

```
SELECT NUMBER(2) FROM DUAL;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: just ask. if i don't have return clause. can i execute it from a SELECT statement too?

Comment: I'm not sure what PL/SQL will do if you have a function without a RETURN statement. I believe it issues a compile-time warning, but try it out.

Comment: @user36 -- some other databases, yes, but not Oracle

Comment: @BobJarvis, there is a compile-time warning, but also at runtime if a return is never encountered the function will raise `ORA-06503: Function returned without value`

Comment: @user3664490 - and, somewhat belatedly, another suggestion - `NUMBER` is a datatype in Oracle, and thus it would be best to give your function a different name - perhaps `MY_NUMBER` or `COMPUTE_NUMBER`. Share and enjoy.